# unbiased variance in Theano

Tags: theano, variance

In numpy we can set `ddof=1` to get the ubiased variance, how is it implemented in theano?

I've looked at [this page](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html) it seems the `theano.tensor.var` function does not support such options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theano.tensor.var` returns the biased sample variance. I'm not aware of a builtin function that returns the unbiased sample variance, but you can obtain it as follows:

Given a vector `x`, use Theano's builtin `var()`, but change the `1/n` divisor to `1/(n-1)`:

```
v = x.var() * x.size / (x.size - 1)
```